# Magento 2 - Use RequireJS in custom module within adminhtml

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

Apologies if this has been asked and answered already.

My objective is to create a Magento 2 custom module that adds a character counter to the edit product page within the Magento 2 Admin. I want to do this by hooking in to RequireJS and add the character counter to the Meta Title and Meta Description fields. I am assuming I have to hook in to RequireJS so that I can access the meta title and description fields. If this is not the way to target those fields and add JavaScript to it, can you recommend how to do this?

With my attempt, I keep getting the "Mismatched anonymous define() module" error.

In my module's `view/adminhtml/layout/default.xml file`, I have the following set:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    layout="admin-1column"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <link src="LinkDigital_CustomInjections::js/metaCounterCode.js"/>
    </head>
    <body/>
</page>
```

In my module's requirejs-config.js file, I have the following:

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            metaCounter: 'LinkDigital_CustomInjections/js/metaCounterCode'
        }
    },
    deps: ["jquery"]
};
```

In my module's `view/adminhtml/web/js/metaCounterCode.js` file, I have the following:

```
function textCounter( field, countfield, maxlimit ) {
       if ( field.value.length > maxlimit ) {
          field.value = field.value.substring( 0, maxlimit );
          field.blur();
          field.focus();
          return false;
       } else {
          countfield.value = maxlimit - field.value.length;
       }
  }
define(["jquery"],function($){
  //Target meta title and description fields under "Search Engine Optimization" section

});
```

Answer (score 0):

For call js file in head from layout try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    layout="admin-1column"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <js src="js/metaCounterCode.js"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

If you have called the file in the head from layout, you do not need to call it in the `requiredjs-config.js` file, you can remove the `requiredjs-config.js` file.
Here `view/adminhtml/web/js/metaCounterCode.js`, you can do the following:

```
function textCounter( field, countfield, maxlimit ) {
    if ( field.value.length > maxlimit ) {
        field.value = field.value.substring( 0, maxlimit );
        field.blur();
        field.focus();
        return false;
    } else {
        countfield.value = maxlimit - field.value.length;
    }
}

define(["jquery"], textCounter( 'field', 'countfield', 'maxlimit' ));
```

But you must change the parameters method with the right ones.